# Android Studio becomes slow and unresponsive

Tags: performance, android-studio

When I use Android Studio, it always gets very slow even when restarting the program and the computer. It takes minutes to load Android Studio, build and sync the project, do normal functions (Sometimes), and to close Android Studio.

Not only that but sometimes it may also get unresponsive (That is usually fixed after a while), and very rarely it might get so unresponsive, that force-closing Android Studio can take several minutes.

It's really becoming a problem, I tried many other questions that already had answers here in Stack Overflow, but they don't work or the question is slightly different from mine.

**Is there any way to fix it?**, Or anything that can help make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

No ,I think it depends what computer you have , if it has 4GB RAM or slow proccesor  the Android Studio will work very slow.

Comment: I have a Dell Precision 5520 with i7 and 32gb RAM. The new android studio beta 3.4 is amazingly slow, build times are 30 min for a normally 30 sec build. My CPUs are consistenly slammed even when no gradle or other indexing operations are happening. very very strange and infuriating.